# Access db table update replace

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I want to update an access database table 'TableName' by replacing strings in a column 'ColName' as the following:

```
 Dim Sql As String = "UPDATE [" & TableName & "] SET [" & ColName & "] = REPLACE([" & ColName & "], '" & OldPart & "', '" & NewPart & "')"  
 Dim Cmd As new OleDbCommand
 Cmd.Connection = My data bsae connection string
 Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 Cmd.CommandText = Sql
 Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and I got the following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the field you're updating a text field?

Comment: it means the data type of the value you're setting the field to to doesn't match the data type of the column you're putting it in. Perhaps you're trying to update a numeric field with text, for instance, or the other way round. You can google your error message and get 1000s of results, including https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-a-message-about-data-type-mismatch-c75b62ff-bcfd-4bb0-83f8-8129f372d59f

Comment: The column is a 'Long text' or 'Memo' format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some empty fields, so try this:

```
Dim Sql As String = "UPDATE [" & TableName & "] SET [" & ColName & "] = REPLACE([" & ColName & "], '" & OldPart & "', '" & NewPart & "') WHERE [" & ColName & "] Is Not Null"
```

Comment: Worked well. Thank you very much.